# NullPointerException LibGDX Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Okay so I have three screens MyGame screen, a GameScreen screen and a MainMenuScreen. I'm trying to setup so that when I touch the screen it goes to the main render screen. When I touch it nothing happens so I played it in a window using the space bar instead. This is MyGame:

```
package com.faturbansloth.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;

public class MyGame extends Game  {


public BitmapFont font;
public SpriteBatch batch;
public void create(){
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    font = new BitmapFont();
    this.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));



}
public void render(){
    super.render();
}

public void dispose(){
    font.dispose();
    batch.dispose();
}

}
```

And this is the error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException:     java.lang.NullPointerException
at     com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:113)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.draw(SpriteBatch.java:631)
at com.faturbansloth.mygdxgame.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:90)
at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
at com.faturbansloth.mygdxgame.MyGame.render(MyGame.java:21)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:187)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:110)
```

**EDIT**
Sorry guys here is the looonnnggg GameScreen:

```
package com.faturbansloth.mygdxgame;






import java.util.Iterator;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Peripheral;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Array;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;

public class GameScreen implements Screen {
final MyGame game;


OrthographicCamera camera;
Vector3 touch;
boolean paused;
Rectangle ship;
boolean available;
Array<Rectangle> asteroids;
long lastDropTime;



public GameScreen(final MyGame gam) {
    this.game = gam;


    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(true,1080,1920);


    touch = new Vector3();

    available = Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Peripheral.Accelerometer);

    ship = new Rectangle();
    ship.x = 1080 / 2 - 128 / 2;
    ship.y = 1600;
    ship.width = 128;
    ship.height = 128;



    asteroids = new Array<Rectangle>();
    spawnAsteroi(); 
}

private void spawnAsteroi(){
    Rectangle asteroi = new Rectangle();
    asteroi.x = MathUtils.random(0, 1080 - 100);
    asteroi.y = 0;
    asteroi.height = 100;
    asteroi.width = 100;
    asteroids.add(asteroi); 
    lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime(); 

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0F, 0F, 0F, 1F);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update(); 







    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    game.batch.begin();
    for(Rectangle asteroi: asteroids){
          game.batch.draw(Assets.texture_asteroi, asteroi.x, asteroi.y);
            }

                Assets.font.draw(game.batch, "Asteroids!", 366, 1100);

                game.batch.draw(Assets.ship, ship.x, ship.y);


                 if(paused){
                     game.batch.draw(Assets.pause, 0, 0);
                 }




    game.batch.end();
    if(paused){
        if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            paused = false;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }else{
        generalUpdate();

    }

     if(ship.x < 0) ship.x = 0;
     if(ship.x > 1080 - 128) ship.x = 1080 - 128;

     if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) spawnAsteroi(); 
     Iterator<Rectangle> iter = asteroids.iterator();
     while(iter.hasNext()){
         Rectangle asteroi = iter.next();
         asteroi.y +=200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
         if(asteroi.y + 100 < 0) iter.remove();
         if(asteroi.overlaps(ship)){
             iter.remove();
         }

     }
    }



@Override
public void dispose() {
    game.batch.dispose();
    Assets.texture_asteroi.dispose(); 


}




public void generalUpdate(){

    ship.x -= Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();

    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SPACE) || (Gdx.input.isTouched())){
        paused = true;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}



@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void show() {


}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}


}
```

And here is the MainMenuScreen:

```
package com.faturbansloth.mygdxgame;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.freetype.FreeTypeFontGenerator;

public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen {
final MyGame game;

OrthographicCamera camera;


public MainMenuScreen(final MyGame gam) {
    game = gam;

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 1080, 1920);

}

public void render(float delta){
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();

    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined); 

    game.batch.begin();
    FreeTypeFontGenerator gen = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("font1.otf")); 
    game.font = gen.generateFont(100);
    game.font.getRegion().getTexture().setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    game.font.setColor(Color.valueOf("7a7d7d")); 

    game.font.draw(game.batch, "Welcome to Asteroids!", 184, 800);
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "Tap anywhere to begin.", 184, 500);
    game.batch.end();

    if(Gdx.input.isTouched() || Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.SPACE)){
        game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
        dispose1();

    }




}

private void dispose1() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void show() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void hide() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void pause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void resume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

The errors are:

```
Super.render() for MyGame
game.batch.draw(Assets.texture_asteroi, asteroi.x, asteroi.y
```

Comment: past your `MainMenuScreen`

Comment: When people ask you to post code, be aware that we mean only _relevant_ code. For example, in your GameScreen class there are several empty methods. We don't need to see them (since they are doing absolutely nothing).

Comment: Okay thanks, fairly new. Will keep in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure of your game looks very strange... I can't find the exactly place in your code where is the error, but you should change your game structure and it will solve the problem.

Few global tips:

1. `Super.render()` - just remove it you don't need to render anything in your `MyGame class`, it is just main class which initialise resources and shows first game screen.
2. Why do you send the Game object to your screens? Just create SpriteBatch for every screen you star, you should not use the same `SpriteBatch` for all your screens.
3. Move your `BitmapFont font;` to separate singleton, which will manage all graphic resources in your game.

I am sure if you will create correct game structure, with separate `SpriteBatch` for every screen, and without sanding your MyGame to other places it will solve the problem.